# How Do I Transfer Command Line Arguments Into A RubyMotion Application?

Tags: rubymotion

I want my RubyMotion application to be able to access command line arguments when calling the iOS simulator.

`rake foo=bar`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the `motion-env`gem (https://github.com/clayallsopp/motion-env)

```
#gemfile
gem "motion-env"
```

now call `bundler install`.

Then change your rake file to read the parameters and to set them on the app object

```
#rakefile
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
    app.name = 'my cool app'
    app.env['foo'] = ENV['foo']
end
```

Finally access the variable in your application

```
class AppDelegate
    def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: options)
        puts "ENVIRONMENT=#{ENV['foo']}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this answer is for helping folks who came here based on the question in the title. You can't actually pass command line arguments to an iOS application as there's no command line.

There's a gem for handling command line arguments to RubyMotion applications. It's called [motion-osx-cli](https://github.com/MarkVillacampa/motion-osx-cli)

The documentation is actually pretty clear on how to use it for making command line apps or GUI apps that handle cli input.

That gem was based on the instructions found in [this post on how to make command line apps with RubyMotion](http://chen.do/blog/2013/10/04/building-a-command-line-os-x-app-with-rubymotion/).